# should i test for javascript image object support?

Tags: javascript, object-detection

I've just started using object detection to ensure certain javascript object support, eg: XMLHttpRequest. Should I be testing ALL javascript objects, including seemingly ubiquitous objects such as Image?

Comment: I'd say you're safe to assume that all browsers will have image support. and those that don't either don't have JS to begin with (e.g. Lynx) or are so old you shouldn't even waste any time on them.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest detection is used because different browsers have different objects to handle AJAX calls (XMLHttpRequest or ActiveXObject in older IE versions).
all modern browsers support images

Comment: I suggest you use jQuery. The tests will be handled and cross browser alternatives found for you